# Where does one obtain a RAREP?

Tags: weather

Where can I find Radar Weather Reports ([RAREPs](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/pilot_handbook/media/PHAK%20-%20Chapter%2012.pdf))? Are they still used? They are not anywhere on the [aviationweather.gov](http://www.aviationweather.gov/) website.

Comment: "follow up" to what?

Comment: follow up question to 'how does one obtain a RAREP?'

Comment: Doesn't "how" answer the "where"? Can you link the original question?

Comment: I understand why this question was initially unclear, but I'm not sure why it's unclear after Pondlife's edit. Can close voter please explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coded RAREPs (Radar Weather Reports) and SDs (Storm Detections) may still be used to exchange data between radar stations, but for human users they seem to have been superseded by visual displays that provide a more human-friendly visualization of the same information, such as at http://www.aviationweather.gov/radar.  The PHAK you linked to (published in 2008) is likely out of date on this.  (But this is the most recent PHAK available.)

From http://weatherjackwilliams.com/answers-weather-radar/ :

> The NWS Aviation Weather Center (AWC) doesn’t have any links to the
>   coded SD/ROB reports, but does link to the Radar Summary chart, which
>   is complied from these  reports.

This information is also incorporated into a standard weather briefing for a particular flight plan.  The DUAT system used to provide an "SD (Radar Weather Reports)" section in its briefings, but DUAT is no longer available.  [DUATS](http://duats.com) instead has a section titled "Radar Summaries" in its briefings.

Comment: The system wouldn't let me include more than two links in my answer.  Here's the link to DUATS: https://www.duats.com/

Comment: Welcome to aviation.se Kiri!